# Spring security ldap authenticate first

Tags: ldap, spring-security

I have set up an ldap authentication using the following configuration.  I just need to user to authenticate to the LDAP data store, then have their session get an authentication token.  From reading the docs, this is what I am thinking is supposed to happen:

1. Authenticate as the manager, find the users full dn based on search criteria
2. Attempt to bind as the user (using their full dn) and the provided password

The logs dont seem to give enough information as to why this is failing.  It just says invalid credentials - when I know they are valid.  My thoughts are one of the following is happening:

1. The users full DN is not being found, and they are just being authenticated with the username
2. It is trying to do a password compare, vs actually trying to bind to the directory

Configuration:

```
<ldap-server 
    url="ldap://adapps.company.com:389/dc=company,dc=com" 
    manager-dn="cn=fulluserdn,dc=company,dc=com" 
    manager-password="password"/>
<ldap-user-service user-search-base="" user-search-filter="(samaccountname={0})"/>  
<authentication-manager>
<ldap-authentication-provider user-search-filter="(samaccountname={0})" user-search-base="dc=company,dc=com"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

Error logs:

```
[DEBUG,FilterBasedLdapUserSearch] Searching for user 'test', with user search [ searchFilter: '(samaccountname={0})', searchBase: 'dc=company,dc=com', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
[DEBUG,AbstractContextSource] Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://adapps.company.com:389/dc=company,dc=com'
[INFO,SpringSecurityLdapTemplate] Ignoring PartialResultException
[DEBUG,XmlWebApplicationContext] Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent[source=org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@488b5f0b: Principal: test; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd148a: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 0718B7EED3F930C63C03DA97C4344CBD; Not granted any authorities]
[DEBUG,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter] Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
[DEBUG,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter] Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
[DEBUG,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter] Delegating to authentication failure handlerorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@395158
[DEBUG,TokenBasedRememberMeServices] Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful.
[DEBUG,TokenBasedRememberMeServices] Cancelling cookie
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was teat the LDAP server was running on a different port, but the normal port was still open.